# TypeError: Class constructor Carousel cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

This is the Error it is showing ..

```
TypeError: Class constructor Carousel cannot be invoked without 'new'
renderWithHooks
G:/mi-store-clone/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14985
  14982 |   }
  14983 | }
  14984 | 
> 14985 | var children = Component(props, secondArg); // Check if there was a render phase update
        | ^  14986 | 
  14987 | if (didScheduleRenderPhaseUpdateDuringThisPass) {
  14988 |   // Keep rendering in a loop for as long as render phase updates continue to
View compiled
mountIndeterminateComponent
G:/mi-store-clone/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17811
  17808 | 
  17809 |   setIsRendering(true);
  17810 |   ReactCurrentOwner$1.current = workInProgress;
> 17811 |   value = renderWithHooks(null, workInProgress, Component, props, context, renderLanes);
        | ^  17812 |   setIsRendering(false);
  17813 | } // React DevTools reads this flag.
  17814 |
```

This is my slider.js

```
import { Carousel } from 'bootstrap'
import React from 'react'

const Slider = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Carousel>
                
            </Carousel>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Slider
```

This is App.js

```
import './App.css';
import PreNavBar from './components/PreNavbar'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar.js'
import Slider from './components/Slider';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <PreNavBar/> 
      <Navbar/>
      <Slider/>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am currently Learning how to implement Carousel in React.js . I have no Idea why this error is coming.
I saw the Earlier post where ppl have same doubt but none of them have similar problem like me . I have implement just the simple code
Also i installed react-bootstrap and bootstrap for this project already ..
Please Help !

Comment: You likely need to use the [react version of Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io)

Comment: having same issue, did you solve it?